# Simple javascript form validation won't return true

Tags: javascript, html

I created this function where it checks for multiple textboxes if they have values onsubmit. Basically it is a javascript form validator. When there are empty textboxes, form shouldn't submit and alert the user that there are required fields. Now, this works for me perfectly, however, when there are values already and the form is submitted, it still doesn't submit even though it should. I created an if statement to check if the errorString is empty or null, if it is, the form should submit but what happens is that it alerts the user with a blank string. I think the code is still going inside the if(errorString!=null || errorString=="") statement even though it shouldn't.

Thanks in advance

Please see my code below:

```
            function validateForm()
        {
            var txtTitle = document.forms["actionStepsForm"]["txtTitle"].value;
    var txtRequestor = document.forms["actionStepsForm"]["txtRequestor"].value;
            var txtReprocessingRequest = document.forms["actionStepsForm"]["txtReprocessingRequest"].value;

            document.getElementById('rowCount').value = counter-1;

    var errorString = "";

            if (txtTitle==null || txtTitle=="")
            {
                errorString += "Title field is required. \n";
            }
            if (txtRequestor==null || txtRequestor=="")
            {
                errorString += "Requestor field is required. \n";
            }
            if (txtReprocessingRequest==null || txtReprocessingRequest=="")
            {
                errorString += "Reprocessing request FR is required. \n";
            }


            if (errorString!=null || errorString!="")
            {
                alert(errorString);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }

//implementation if HTML form
<form name="actionStepsForm" id="actionStepsForm" action="add_reprocessing.php?action=add" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

errorString can never be null because you've initialized it with "" so you can remove the condition "errorString != null".

It should become

```
        if (errorString!="")
        {
            alert(errorString);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: I checked this answer because of the added information the initialization of "" is not equal to null. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct condition should be

```
if (errorString != null && errorString != "")
```

otherwise the engine evaluated the 'errorString != null' condition, which evaluates to true (since errorString is "" and not null), and enter the code block.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (errorString!=null || errorString!="")
```

to

```
if (errorString!=null && errorString!="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two 'not' statements that cancel each other out (one must always be false). Change it to:

```
    if (errorString!=null && errorString!="")
    {
        alert(errorString);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: does this mean I need to change

`if (txtTitle==null || txtTitle=="")`

to

`if (txtTitle==null && txtTitle=="")`

??

Comment: No, because they are positive statements. It may be true that txtTitle is equal to null or equal to "". It will always be true however that 1 != 2 || 1 != 1 because one of the values is wrong. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The wrong line is the one everyone pointed out:

```
if (errorString!=null || errorString!="")
```

**But** I would like to point that you *don't need* to check for `errorString!=null` because you already created the variable as an empty string in the beginning of your code:

```
var errorString = ""; //created errorString as empty string
```

Therefore it will never actually be `null`, because you never set it as null anywhere (that is, you never set it as `errorString = null`).

If there are no errors, it will be an empty string always. So this will suffice:

```
        if (errorString!="") //if errorString is different than what we created at `var`
        {
            alert(errorString);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try With Different Logic**. You can use bellow code for check all four(4) condition for validation like not null, not blank, not undefined and not zero only use this code (!(!(variable))) in javascript and jquery.

```
function myFunction() {
        var errorString;  //The Values can be like as null,blank,undefined,zero you can test

         if(!(!(errorString)))  //this condition is important
         {
         alert("errorString"+errorString);
         } 
         else 
         {
            alert("errorStringis "+errorString);
        }

        }
```